# Child Leaving Parent on Left Side

Tags: html, css, canvas

I have a `canvas` item inside of a container. I am expecting the `canvas` to not be able to extend past its container on the left side. I have tried several solutions on here but have yet to have any luck. My legend will be hidden inside the container but once the container reaches the right border of my chart, the container starts to push the chart to the left, outside of the container.

CSS:

```
.chart-container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    border: 1px solid red;
    justify-content: center;
}
#totalChartLegend, #pdChartLegend {
    list-style-type: square;
    list-style-position: inside;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #666;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 280px;
    width: 140px;


    border: 1px solid green;
    margin-top: 40px;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#totalChartLegend li, #pdChartLegend li{
  display: block;

}
#totalChartLegend li.hidden, #pdChartLegend li.hidden{
  color: rgba(102, 102, 102, .4);
}
#totalChartLegend li span, #pdChartLegend li span{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 15px;
  width: 35px;
  margin-right: 10px;

}
#totalChart, #pdChart{
    border: 1px solid blue;

}
```

HTML

```
<section id="totalChartContainer" class="chart-container">
    <canvas id="totalChart" width="900" height="400"></canvas>
    <span id="totalChartLegend"></span>
</section>
```

Picture (blue = child, red = parent)

[image]

**EDIT 1**

My chart will go all the way to the left side of the browser if I continue to collapse the browser's width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed parent CSS to

```
.chart-container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    border: 1px solid red;
    justify-content: center;
    min-width:900px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }        
        .chart-container {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            border: 1px solid red;
            justify-content: center;
        }        
        #totalChartLegend,
        #pdChartLegend {
            list-style-type: square;
            list-style-position: inside;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 15px;
            color: #666;
            overflow-y: auto;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            height: 280px;
            width: 140px;
            border: 1px solid green;
            margin-top: 40px;
            text-align: left;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }        
        #totalChartLegend li,
        #pdChartLegend li {
            display: block;
        }        
        #totalChartLegend li.hidden,
        #pdChartLegend li.hidden {
            color: rgba(102, 102, 102, .4);
        }        
        #totalChartLegend li span,
        #pdChartLegend li span {
            display: inline-block;
            height: 15px;
            width: 35px;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }        
        #totalChart,
        #pdChart {
            border: 1px solid blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <section id="totalChartContainer" class="chart-container">
                <canvas id="totalChart" width="900" height="400"></canvas>
                <span id="totalChartLegend"></span>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```